# PHP - Inserting Data with 24h limits

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I've got a code made by me that is a simple form POST that inserts into db some data. But my objective is... Limit the Inserts per Day.

Example: A user only can insert data into db per day, X user inserted today a 18h00, now only tomorrow will be able to insert again at 18h00.

Can someone tell how to do it?... How to limit it?

Comment: How many times a user can insert per day? what is your database structure?

Answer (score 1):

Everytime a user inserts, check the last insert time. If the time is less than 24 hours, deny it.

For this you need to record the insert time and the user (name or id) when someone inserts.

Comment: humm ok i see.Thank you.